# find a class item in array in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, search, arraylist, indexing

**I have arraylist class and want to find the person inside**

```
 val personlist : ArrayList<Person>
 
 personlist.add("Max","Mustermann","24")
 
 val searchingfield = searchEt.text.toString()
 
 val foundNames = personlist.filter { it.startsWith(searchingfield)}
```

Looking for smth smilar to this.

I want to find the person inside of the array list, with his name, surname or age, when I clicked the search button

Answer (score 0):

So when you are doing a filter on `personList` the `it` in the lambda refers to any individual element in `personList` - so that would be of type `Person`.

`Person` is not going to have a `startsWith` function unless you've defined one. You will probably need to look at the fields. For example, if it has surname and you just want to compare by equality, you would do something like this:

```
val foundNames = personlist.filter {
    it.surname == searchingfield
}
```

You can also rename the lambda parameter to something more clear:

```
val foundNames = personlist.filter { person ->
    person.surname == searchingfield
}
```

The contents of the lambda is up to you, just know that `it` is a `Person` and not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
val foundNames = personlist.filter {
it.name == searchingfield || it.surname == searchingfield || it.age == searchingfield }
```

Comment: But the problem then is, found names is not a Person its just a value then.
I want to have foudnNames as Person